# Rendering nested routes from a seperate file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm moving the routes to a separate file to keep App.js a bit cleaner. Is there a better way to do this cause the routes that requires_auth needs to be wrapped with the `ProtectedRoute` which will check if the user is logged in or not. The code below works but I think I'm duplicating the `ProtectedRoute` for each of the route that requires it.

**app.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Layout from './pages/layouts/Layout';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/userContext';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import { routes } from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>      
          {routes.map((route, index) => {
            return route.requires_auth ?
              <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />} key={index}>
                <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
              </Route>
              :
              <Route key={index} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
          })}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**routes.js**

```
import CreatePostPage from "./pages/CreatePostPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import PostDetailPage from "./pages/PostDetailPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";

export const routes = [
  { path: '/', element: <HomePage />},
  { path: '/login', element: <LoginPage />},
  { path: '/register', element: <RegisterPage />},
  { path: '/post/create', element: <CreatePostPage />, requires_auth: true},
  { path: '/post/:id', element: <PostDetailPage />, requires_auth: true },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContext } from '../contexts/userContext';

function ProtectedRoute({ element }) {
  const { isLoggedIn } = useContext(UserContext);

  return isLoggedIn ? element : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

And update App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import Layout from './pages/layouts/Layout';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/userContext';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import { routes } from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          {routes.map((route, index) => (
            <Route 
              key={index} 
              path={route.path} 
              element={route.requires_auth ? 
                  <ProtectedRoute element={route.element} /> : 
                  route.element
              }
            />
          ))}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code below works but I think I'm duplicating the `ProtectedRoute`
> for each of the route that requires it.

You are, but this is completely ok and won't cause any major issues/problems.

If you are wanting to make the code a bit more ***DRY*** then you can refactor  the map callback to conditionally render the `ProtectedRoute` or an `Outlet`.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>      
          {routes.map((route) => (
            <Route
             key={route.path}
             element={route.requires_auth ? <ProtectedRoute /> : <Outlet />} 
            >
              <Route path={route.path} element={route.element} />
            </Route>
          ))}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}
```

This *still* renders a wrapper route for each route you want to render, so if the goal is to reduce what is rendered to the DOM then I suggest the following refactor that executes two filter/maps for each type of route that should be rendered.

Example:

```
const renderRoute = route => (
  <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.element} />
);

function App() {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
            {routes
              .filter(route => route.requires_auth)
              .map(renderRoute)
            }
          </Route>
          {routes
            .filter(route => !route.requires_auth)
            .map(renderRoute)
          }
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}
```

Of course, it might just be easier to configure it all right in the `routes.js` file.

Example:

```
import Layout from './pages/layouts/Layout';
import CreatePostPage from "./pages/CreatePostPage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import PostDetailPage from "./pages/PostDetailPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';

export const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <HomePage />},
      { path: 'login', element: <LoginPage />},
      { path: 'register', element: <RegisterPage />},
      {
        path: 'post',
        element: <ProtectedRoute />,
        children: [
          { path: 'create', element: <CreatePostPage />,
          { path: ':id', element: <PostDetailPage />,
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

```
import './App.css';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserContextProvider } from './contexts/userContext';
import { routes } from './routes';

function App() {
  const appRoutes = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      {appRoutes}
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```